# Transform a list of dict from a column in a column of list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe with list of dict inside.

[image]

Here is the first element of the 'reviews' column:

[image]

I would like to extract 'item_id' et 'recommend' key to put them in new column of the previous dataframe like this:

[image]

Comment: What libraries are you using? What have you tried?
You should give us some code to understand how you are trying to achieve that and with what tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying this on Pandas dataframe, you can use custom function or a lambda function to extract key values from a list of dicts

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'x',
                    'B': [[{'Fruits': 'Apple', 'Vegetables': 'Tomato'},
                         {  'Fruits': 'Orange', 'Vegetables': 'Onion'},
                         {'Fruits': 'Mango', 'Vegetables': 'Potato'}]]})

print(df)
```

[image]

```py
key = 'Fruits'
df[key] = df['B'].apply(lambda ls: [d[key] for d in ls])

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: You should rather add the actual code in your answer instead of an image ;)